# Declaring a set parameter in VB

Tags: vb.net, dll, parameters

I have a DLL I made that is a custom button, and a regular form. To have the button display its properties (it will just show up as a regular button in the designer) the user must enter

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CustomButton1.Initialize(Width, Height, ButtonText)
End Sub
```

However, I want to have a set parameter so the user can do:

```
CustomButton1.Initialize(Textlocation.Top)
```

Such as what is done when creating a messagebox and setting the type:

```
MsgBox("MessageBoxText", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Great question! If you made a DLL you can specify these properties in your DLL for your button. Then you can call this anytime, have you tried this?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an Enum:

```
Enum TextLocation
    Top
    Bottom
    ...
End Enum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the method. Assuming you have something like this:

```
Public Sub Initialize(width As Integer, height As Integer, buttonText As String)
    ' Or however it’s declared
End Sub
```

declare this beneath it:

```
Public Sub Initialize(location As TextLocation)
    Select Case location
        Case TextLocation.Top
            Me.Initialize(appropriate presets)
        …
    End Select
End Sub
```

And that’s really it!